# Compare two lists item where list contains dictionary item

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
a = [{'1':'value1'},{'2':'value2'}]
b = [{'x':'value1'},{'y':'hello'},{'z':'value1'}]
```

I want to compare between these two list where if `value1` matches then it will return the all the key of list `b`. I want a result like this:

```
c= ['x','z']
```

Comment: for each value, or for all values?

Comment: Your item structure is strange - can `a` and `b` be dictionaries of multiple items rather than lists of single-item dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading this as: "Return a list of all keys `k` from dictionaries `d` in list `b` such that the value of `k` in `d` is the same as the value of some key in some dictionary from list `a`"

```
val_set = {v for d in a for v in d.values()}
output = [k for d in b for k, v in d.items() if v in val_set]
print(output)
#['x', 'z']
```

Comment: Better implementation!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like this:

```
a = [{'1':'value1'},{'2':'value2'}]
b = [{'x':'value1'},{'y':'hello'},{'z':'value1'}]
c = [w.keys()[0] for q in a for w in b if q.values()[0] == w.values()[0]]
print(c)
```

output:

```
['x', 'z']
```

---

Which is equivalent to:

```
a = [{'1':'value1'},{'2':'value2'}]
b = [{'x':'value1'},{'y':'hello'},{'z':'value1'}]
c = []
for q in a:
    for w in b:
        if q.values()[0] == w.values()[0]:
            c.append(w.keys()[0])
print(c)
```